# Delete query with inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

## query

```
DELETE `contact`
FROM `contact` ct
INNER JOIN `contact_user` cu ON cu.contact_id=ct.id
WHERE ct.id=4 && ct.block_id=5671 && cu.user_id=1
```

## error

> Fatal: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1109 Unknown
>   table 'contact' in MULTI DELETE; SQL: DELETE `contact` FROM `contact`
>   ct INNER JOIN `contact_user` cu ON cu.contact_id=ct.id WHERE ct.id=4
>   && ct.block_id=5671 && cu.user_id=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have defined `Alias name` to your table `contact` you need to use alias name instead of original table name. Try this

```
DELETE ct 
FROM   contact ct 
       INNER JOIN contact_user cu 
               ON cu.contact_id = ct.id 
WHERE  ct.id = 4 
       AND ct.block_id = 5671 
       AND cu.user_id = 1
```

or remove the alias name for `contact` table

```
DELETE contact 
FROM   contact 
       INNER JOIN contact_user cu 
               ON cu.contact_id = contact.id 
WHERE  contact.id = 4 
       AND contact.block_id = 5671 
       AND cu.user_id = 1
```

Answer (score 4):

Because you have defined an alias for the table, you should use it. Also replace `&&` with `and`.

```
DELETE `ct` --`contact`
FROM `contact` ct
INNER JOIN `contact_user` cu ON cu.contact_id=ct.id
WHERE ct.id=4 and ct.block_id=5671 and cu.user_id=1
```